Mongo BI Connnector not connecting with mongodb atlas
enter image description here
unable to load MongoDB information: failed to create admin session for loading server cluster information: unable to execute command: server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: mymongdbclusterurl.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: EOF } Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: EOF
i have also whitelisted the ip address on the cloud cluster and also but still having these issues

Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

What do you mean by "Mongo BI Connnector not connectiong"? The Mongo BI Connnector is a driver to connect a SQL tool to a NoSQL MongoDB. On Atlas you can simple enable it.

iam using cubejs with has sql queries the this connector basically translates my sql queries to mongodb and selects data from there now the probelm is when i want to connect using mongosqld.yml configuration file it does not connect and gives above error

As said, on Atlas you don't need to configure any mongosqld, it's required for on-premise MongoDB. Just enable it in Atlas UI and then you can connect.

can you guide me how to enable the bi connector ?

You set it in Additional Settings, see Configure Additional Settings. Note, BI Connector is available only for M10 and up, i.e. it is not available in MongoDB Free cluster nor in Serverless Cluster.

i checked in the additional settings of it has already blue tick enabled
but when i run below command to connect with mongodb atlas using
mongosqld --config  conf/mongosqld.yml    it gives errors failed to create admin session for loading server cluster information: unable to execute command: server selection error: context deadline exceeded

Once again, you don't need to start mongosqld - it is already included and running in the Atlas cluster. Just connect by following https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/bi-connection/#std-label-bic-connection-tutorials

let me give you details of my project so then you can help me in a better way .

We are working on a project that utilizes both MySQL and MongoDB databases, alongside Cube.js for data processing. Our system operates as follows:
Cube.js Server Initialization: When the Cube.js server starts, it reads all SQL queries from the schema directory.
Data Retrieval: The server sends requests to MongoDB to fetch the necessary data.
Aggregation and Storage: The retrieved data is then processed and the aggregation results are stored in the MySQL database.

Given that MySQL is a relational database and MongoDB is non-relational (and does not natively support SQL queries), we use the MongoDB BI Connector. This connector acts as a translator, converting SQL queries into MongoDB-compatible queries and fetching the required data.
To facilitate this, MongoDB BI provides a mongosqld.yml configuration file for local use. This file contains all the necessary MongoDB details. When we run this file, it establishes a connection with the online MongoDB database. Once the connection is successfully established,

we start the Cube.js server, which then performs its operations as described above.

You are wrong. Again, you need to install and run MongoDB BI Connector only if your MongoDB runs on your premises. When you use MongoDB Atlas, then it is included and you don't need to configure anything, just enable it. Then your Cube.js can simply connect.

projects are on my local system when i use local mongodb works well but not with online mongodb atlas

Yes, I think meanwhile I wrote this 3 times. MongoDB BI Connector works only on local MongoDB but not on Atlas.
